# Django media url mismatch with digitalocean spaces

Tags: django, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, django-settings

I have a droplet running a django app on digital ocean using digital ocean spaces.I have managed to set up the spaces which runs well with static files using a cdn. However, my problem lies with the uploaded media files.I am facing an issue of mismatch in the urls of the uploaded file served by django and what the actual  path of the uploaded files in the spaces.
For example if i upload a file using models:

```
attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='Mailserver/',blank=True,null=True)
```

and the path of the file returned when I click on it, returns an error with the path as
'https://freelance.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/media/Mailserver/download.png' which is wrong because the correct path of the file uploaded to spaces is: 'https://freelance.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/freelance/media/Mailserver/download.png'

This is my settings config:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '****************************'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '*****************************'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'freelance'
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://freelance.ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'freelance.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com'
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
  }
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
STATIC_URL = '{}/{}/'.format(AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, 'static')
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = '{}/{}/'.format(AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIA_ROOT)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

And custom_storages looks like:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
from django.conf import settings

class StaticStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    bucket_name = settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    location = settings.STATIC_ROOT

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    bucket_name = settings.AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
    location = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

I have tried creating folders and changing directories to no avail. I don't have a clue on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who encounters a similar problem,i came up with a solution,just edit your custom domain as:

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'freelance.ams3.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/freelance'
```

where by 'freelance' is the name of your bucket spaces name